# Access denied while writing a file on a shared drive

Tags: java, smb

I have a byte[] representing an .xml file which I have to save on a shared drive (mapped with F:/targetFolderName). Both my class and the shared drive are in Windows.
I'm 100% sure that the user I'm logged in with has full control over the shared folder, and the service that runs my class is executed by that same user (also, I can manually access the shared drive and create/delete/modify folders and files).

I tried this simpler method:

```
public static void saveFile (String path, String fileName, byte[] fileByte) throws Exception {
        File outputfile = new File(path + fileName);
        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new  FileOutputStream(outputfile));
        outputStream.write(fileByte);
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

and another one, using smb and jcifs:

```
public static void saveFile (byte[] file, String domain, String user, String password, String basePath, String fileName) throws Exception {
        
        if (fileName != null && (!fileName.contains(".") || fileName.trim().length() < 3)) throw new Exception("File name [" + fileName + "] not valid: must be in the form 'name.extension'.");
        
        try {
            if (basePath.length() < 7 || !basePath.substring(0, 6).equals("smb://")) basePath = "smb://" + basePath;
            String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            if (!basePath.substring(basePath.length() - 1).equals(separator)) basePath += separator;
            if (domain == null) domain = "DOMAIN";
            
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(file);
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication (domain, user, password);
            SmbFile outFile = new SmbFile (basePath + fileName, auth);
            OutputStream out = outFile.getOutputStream();
            
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = in.read (buffer)) > 0) out.write (buffer, 0, len);
            out.close ();
            in.close ();
            
            System.out.println("Ffile [" +  basePath + fileName + "] saved correctly.".replace("smb:", ""));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }       
    }
```

both throw an Exception, the forst one saying *java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: F:/targetFolderName/fileName.xml*, the second one saying *jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Access is denied*.
I assume that the first method is claiming that the path does not exist even if it does, because is missing some sort of permission, since the second Exception is so explicit

Also, if i try the first method and save the file locally in C:/randomFolder it works just fine.

I tried using the assigned letter, the machine formal name, and the ip address in the path: same result.

I'm clueless at this point, what am I getting wrong?

Comment: SMB seems to disagree about your statements: `jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Access is denied` is pretty clear. What user are you running the java process as?

Comment: `Files.write(Path.of(path, fileName), fileByte);` is simpler. Try it and tell us what parameters

Comment: @f1sh as I said, the user I'm logged with is the same running the service, and it has full control on the share I'm trying to write into.

Comment: @g00se I tried this version of the first method          

 public static void saveFile (String path, String fileName, byte[] fileByte) throws Exception {
  File outputfile = new File(path + fileName);  
  if (!Files.exists(outputfile.toPath()));
      Files.createDirectories(outputfile.toPath());
  Files.write(outputfile.toPath(), fileByte);
 } 
              
but I'm getting "Unable to determine if root directory exists"

Comment: That's not what I asked